# perl regex ( regular expression ) capturing using parentheses not printing $1 or $2 variables as expected

Tags: regex, perl

OK I am learning how to use regex in perl and here is my code:

```
my $name = 'Tom Anderson';

if( $name =~ /(\w) (\w)/ )
{
    print "Good\n";
    print "$1 + $2";
}
```

outputs: `good m + A`

My understanding is that the regular expression will check `$name` as follows:

a word character followed by a space followed by another word character, this does not work 100%. if somebody enters another name, say a middle name  the if statement still works. I only want two names and nothing else. Why is it succeeding when someone enters a third?

And the capturing using the parentheses when I print the $1 and $2 gives me `m` and `A`. Why is that? Why isn't the capturing giving me `Tom` and `Anderson`?

Comment: `$name =~ /(\w+) (\w+)/` and it will match `\w` class char 1 or many times.

Comment: Ok and if I only want two names and not 3 how do I limit the number?

Comment: `\w` represents letter, and `\w+` represents word. `/(\w+) (\w+)/` matches TWO words separated by space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your regex:

```
$name =~ /(\w+) (\w+)/;
```

You can also anchor this regex to the start and end of the line:

```
$name =~ /^(\w+) (\w+)$/;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just to clarify, the addition of + means match one or more word characters. The \w on its own matches a single word character, so your original regex was matching one character either side of the space.

Comment: How do I limit the regex to two names and not 3?

Comment: Use the second regex that anchors to the start ^ and end $ of the line.